# Automatically ignore files in grep

Tags: grep, bash

Is there any way I could use grep to ignore some files when searching something, something equivalent to svnignore or gitignore? I usually use something like this when searching source code.

```
grep -r something * | grep -v ignore_file1 | grep -v ignore_file2
```

Even if I could set up an alias to grep to ignore these files would be good.

Comment: Tried a few alias and function derivatives, ended up with the one liner I posted below. Great idea! This is a new addition to my shell!

Comment: You may also want to check out bash's GLOBIGNORE variable.  This lets the shell refine the meaning of '*'.  Doesn't help you with grep -r, of course, but it's a handy thing to have in your toolbox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`--exclude` option on grep will also work:

```
grep  perl * --exclude=try* --exclude=tk*
```

This searches for perl in files in the current directory excluding files beginning with `try` or `tk`.

Comment: this sort of helps my need, --exclude and --exclude-dir

Comment: This is basically what I do -- except I turn that into a script in my bin directory, so there's almost no typing.

Comment: I've created an alias for grep with --exclude and exclude-dir and lot other options with colors, makes my grep more easier now

Comment: @ennuikiller - 
$ alias grep='grep -T --color --exclude=ignore_file* --exclude-dir=ignore-dir*'

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) which, among many other features, by default does not search VCS directories like .svn and .git.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -path ./ignore -prune -o -exec grep -r something {} \;
```

What that does is find all files in your current directory excluding the directory (or file) named "ignore", then executes the command grep -r something on each file found in the non-ignored files.

Answer (score 1):

Use shell expansion

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in !(file1_ignore|file2_ignore) 
do
  grep ..... "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks grep does not have filename filtering.
To accomplish what you are trying to do, you can combine find, xargs, and grep commands.
My memory is not good, so the example might not work:

```
find -name "foo" | xargs grep "pattern"
```

Find is flexible, you can use wildcards, ignore case, or use regular expressions.
You may want to read manual pages for full description.

after reading next post, apparently grep does have filename filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimalistic version of .gitignore.  Requires standard utils: awk, sed (because my awk is so lame), egrep:

```
cat > ~/bin/grepignore  #or anywhere you like in your $PATH
egrep -v "`awk '1' ORS=\| .grepignore | sed -e 's/|$//g' ; echo`"
^D
chmod 755 ~/bin/grepignore
cat >> ./.grepignore  #above set to look in cwd
ignorefile_1
...
^D
grep -r something * | grepignore
```

`grepignore` builds a simple alternation clause:

```
egrep -v ignorefile_one|ignorefile_two
```

not incredibly efficient, but good for manual use